# Index exists but sorting still takes time

Tags: postgresql, performance, indexing, postgresql-9.6

I am working on a query which has been used in one of our services.
Below is the query:

```
select  rg.reservationGuestId, rg.reservationId, rg.checkindate,
        rg.checkoutdate, rg.assignedroom , tr.orderDate, tr.assignedDate,
        cast(tr.orderId as char(36)) , g.titleCode, g.firstName,
        g.middleName, g.lastName, g.birthDate, g.genderCode, g.email,
        g.preferredLanguage , cast(a.addressId as char(36)), a.addressTypeCode,
        a.line1, a.line2, a.city, a.state, a.countryCode as aCountryCode,
        a.zip , cast(p.phoneId as char(36)), p.phoneTypeCode,
        p.countryCode as pCountryCode, p.areaCode, p.number
    from  reservationguest rg
    inner join  guest g  ON rg.guestid = g.guestid
    inner join  address a  ON g.guestid = a.guestid
    inner join  phone p  ON g.guestid = p.guestid
    left join  orderdetail tr  ON rg.reservationguestid = tr.reservationguestid
    where  ((0 = 0)
              or  (rg.reservationGuestId in (null))
           )
      and  (('2019-05-01' = 'null')
              or  (rg.checkindate >= '2019-05-01')
           )
      and  (('2019-09-08' = 'null')
              or  (rg.checkindate <= '2019-09-08')
           )
      and  ((1 = 0)
              or  (a.addressTypeCode in ('SHIPPING'))
           )
      and  ((1 = 0)
              or  (p.phoneTypeCode in ('HOME'))
           )
      and  (('' = 'null')
              or  (('' = '')
                      and  (tr.orderDate is null)
                  )
              or  (tr.orderDate = '2019-06-02 00:00:00')
           )
    order by  rg.checkindate, rg.lastmodifieddate
```

The above query takes almost 1150 ms in fetching 161500 records.

Below is the execution plan of this query:

```
Sort  (cost=21727.93..21732.95 rows=2009 width=683) (actual time=928.206..1117.145 rows=161500 loops=1)
  Sort Key: rg.checkindate, rg.lastmodifieddate
  Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 55936kB
  ->  Hash Right Join  (cost=15262.53..21617.71 rows=2009 width=683) (actual time=267.553..576.902 rows=161500 loops=1)
        Hash Cond: ((tr.reservationguestid)::text = (rg.reservationguestid)::text)
        Filter: ((tr.orderdate IS NULL) OR (tr.orderdate = '2019-06-02 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone))
        Rows Removed by Filter: 252112
        ->  Seq Scan on orderdetail tr  (cost=0.00..6047.00 rows=66800 width=69) (actual time=0.018..36.367 rows=66887 loops=1)
        ->  Hash  (cost=15210.52..15210.52 rows=4161 width=255) (actual time=266.789..266.789 rows=18521 loops=1)
              Buckets: 16384 (originally 8192)  Batches: 2 (originally 1)  Memory Usage: 3969kB
              ->  Nested Loop  (cost=5302.72..15210.52 rows=4161 width=255) (actual time=62.445..248.868 rows=18521 loops=1)
                    ->  Hash Join  (cost=5302.30..6748.12 rows=3322 width=258) (actual time=62.378..83.816 rows=6762 loops=1)
                          Hash Cond: ((p.guestid)::text = (g.guestid)::text)
                          ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on phone p  (cost=263.88..1624.42 rows=13883 width=70) (actual time=1.482..13.057 rows=13909 loops=1)
                                Recheck Cond: ((phonetypecode)::text = 'HOME'::text)
                                Heap Blocks: exact=1186
                                ->  Bitmap Index Scan on ix_phone_phonetypecode  (cost=0.00..260.41 rows=13883 width=0) (actual time=1.315..1.315 rows=13909 loops=1)
                                      Index Cond: ((phonetypecode)::text = 'HOME'::text)
                          ->  Hash  (cost=4952.89..4952.89 rows=6842 width=188) (actual time=60.860..60.860 rows=6811 loops=1)
                                Buckets: 8192  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 1664kB
                                ->  Hash Join  (cost=1774.72..4952.89 rows=6842 width=188) (actual time=28.954..56.879 rows=6811 loops=1)
                                      Hash Cond: ((a.guestid)::text = (g.guestid)::text)
                                      ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on address a  (cost=137.45..3221.97 rows=6842 width=100) (actual time=1.174..22.254 rows=6811 loops=1)
                                            Recheck Cond: ((addresstypecode)::text = 'SHIPPING'::text)
                                            Heap Blocks: exact=2290
                                            ->  Bitmap Index Scan on ix_address_addresstypecode  (cost=0.00..135.73 rows=6842 width=0) (actual time=0.877..0.877 rows=6811 loops=1)
                                                  Index Cond: ((addresstypecode)::text = 'SHIPPING'::text)
                                      ->  Hash  (cost=1279.90..1279.90 rows=28590 width=88) (actual time=27.704..27.704 rows=28590 loops=1)
                                            Buckets: 32768  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 3708kB
                                            ->  Seq Scan on guest g  (cost=0.00..1279.90 rows=28590 width=88) (actual time=0.015..17.576 rows=28590 loops=1)
                    ->  Index Scan using ix_reservationguest_guestid_checkindate_lastmodifieddate on reservationguest rg  (cost=0.42..2.53 rows=2 width=129) (actual time=0.015..0.023 rows=3 loops=6762)
                          Index Cond: (((guestid)::text = (g.guestid)::text) AND (checkindate >= '2019-05-01'::date) AND (checkindate <= '2019-09-08'::date))
Planning time: 3.343 ms
Execution time: 1173.074 ms
```

I think the query is pretty much optimized. However, after I remove the `order by` clause, it takes around 550 ms only which is almost half of the total time.

As I have very little knowledge of the internals of PostgreSQL, I am not sure about sorting using index  `ix_reservationguest_guestid_checkindate_lastmodifieddate` because no index name is mentioned with sorting operation in the execution plan.

Questions

- If it does use the index for sorting, then is it the minimal execution time which I can get from Postgres?
- If it does not use the index, then is there any way to improve the performance of sorting?
- Also, what index should I create to avoid Seq Scan of the `orderdetail` table?

Comment: What's with the `0 = 0` and similar checks?

Comment: @404 Its case of parameter handling. the actual condition is v_reservationGuestId is null or reservationGuestId in (v_reservationGuestId).  if the value of the parameter is not passed then fetch all records otherwise use the filter.

Comment: `rg.reservationGuestId in (null)` will never be true you need `rg.reservationGuestId is null`. And get rid of the useless `or` conditions. They tend to confuse the optimizer and make things slower. `'2019-09-08' = 'null'` and  `('' = 'null'` can be replace with `false` - why do you have all those useless additional conditions?

Comment: Casting to `char()` is a code-smell. Why do you want a fixed length data type there? And what is the data type of those columns? Typically casting to `text` would be better if you want to convert a number to a string value. [Don't use the char type](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_char.28n.29)

Answer (score 0):

I see `'null'` and `null`.  Have you used them correctly?

Does `in (null)` work as expected?

Consider cleaning up the query in cases like this:

```
and   (('2019-05-01' = 'null')
   or  (rg.checkindate >= '2019-05-01')
      )
```

`cast(p.phoneId as char(36))` -- This is an example of over-normalization.  The `phoneID` is bigger than the value!

What will the client do with "161500 records"?  I hope you aren't going to display this to some human on a UI !  Consider summarizing the data instead  dumping it.